# Display HTML Content based on a condition

Tags: html, perl, if-statement

In the application we are developing HTML content is written in a perl string which is later returned. There is a usecase where we'd need to show a certain part of the HTML based on the result of a condition.
Since, HTML is only markup, my understanding it's not possible.
Is there a way around this using Perl or something else?(Apart from creating 2 different templates)

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to [watch this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKOqtRMT85s).

Answer (score 3):

You can put different things in a string based on an `if` statement quite easily.

```
my $thing_to_insert = "";
if (condition()) {
    $thing_to_insert = '<div>...</div>';
} else {
    $thing_to_insert = '<p>...</p>';
}
my $html = "<div>$thing_to_insert</div>";
return $html;
```

Use a template language (such as Template Toolkit or Text::Xslate) would usually be a better bet though.

Comment: This hurts my eyes. :D

Comment: I have a large HTML as a string and say one button has to be shown based on the decision. 
The remaining has to be same.
How can I add a perl string in between an HTML.

Looks something like this:

<body ..>
.
.
.
<td> <a href => ..... </td>
.
.
</html>

Comment: @raita — I gave an example in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the decision about what to show as you are constructing the HTML string.

In basic terms, your code would look like this:

```
my $html = '<html><head>... [lots of HTML]';

if ($we_want_to_show_the_button) {
  $html .= '<button> ... [button html] ... </button>';
}

$html .= '[lots more HTML] ... </body></html>';
```

I should note, however, that we've known for twenty years that generating HTML by concatenating strings inside your Perl code is a terrible idea. A much better approach is to put all of your HTML into a template - along with some logic about displaying various bits if various conditions are true.

If you're using the Template Tooikit, that might look something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    ... lots of HTML omitted ...
[% IF we_want_to_show_the_button -%]
    <button> ... </button>
[% END -%]
   ... lots more HTML ...
  </body>
</html>
```